# How do you define variables within cogs?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently trying to migrate most of my code into cogs and I have this function that logs commands.

```py
    async def logging(self, ctx, command):
        output = client.get_channel(channel_id_here)
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "{} command used.".format(command), color = 0x40558a)
        embed.add_field(name = "User:", value = "{}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
        embed.add_field(name = "Server:", value = "{}".format(ctx.message.guild))
        embed.add_field(name = "Channel:", value = "<#{}>".format(ctx.message.channel.id))
        embed.add_field(name = "Full Command:", value = "{}".format(ctx.message.content))
        await output.send(embed = embed)
```

However, when I attempt to call on that function in a command by using:

```py
await logging(self = self, ctx = ctx, command = "whatever")
```

I get an error that says Undefined variable: `logging`. I am new to using cogs and I would appriciate any help you can give.

Comment: Try using `await invoke(logging(ctx, command))` (If I remember correctly)